# React play different audio files at once - working with different refs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, audio, react-hooks

I'm creating a small app that plays an audio file and have some functionalities (loop, stop, mute). My goal is to add some more audio files that all should be played and stopped at once (one button to control all), but each will have a mute button, and  I'm not sure what is the best practice to do so. I used useRef and thought maybe I need to set a refs array but how will I be able to start/stop them all at once, but still have the ability to control the mute separately?

This is my code so far. I guess I should split and have a different component for the audio sounds. Thanks for helping!

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react'
import {ImPlay2} from "react-icons/im"
import {ImStop} from "react-icons/im"
import styled from "styled-components"
import drums from '../loopfiles/DRUMS.mp3'
//import other audio files//

const AudioPlayer = () => {
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [isLooping, setIsLooping] = useState(false);
    const [isOnMute, setIsOnMute] = useState(false);
    const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(drums));
  
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isOnMute) {
            audioRef.current.volume=0;
        } 
        else {
            audioRef.current.volume=1;
        }
      }, [isOnMute]);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isPlaying) {
            audioRef.current.play();
        } else {
            audioRef.current.pause();
            audioRef.current.load();
        }
      }, [isPlaying]);
      useEffect(() => {
        if (isLooping) {
            audioRef.current.loop = true;
        } else {
            audioRef.current.loop = false;
        }
      }, [isLooping]);
  return (
    <div> 
        {!isPlaying ? (
        <button type="button" 
        className="play" 
        onClick={() => setIsPlaying(true)}> 
        <ImPlay2></ImPlay2> Play 
        </button>
        ) : (
        <button type="button"
        className="pause"
        onClick={() => setIsPlaying(false)}> 
        <ImStop></ImStop> Stop 
        </button> 
        )}
        <Flex>
            <Switcher selected={isLooping} />
            <Text
            onClick={() => setIsLooping(true)}>
            Loop
            </Text>
            <Text
            onClick={() => setIsLooping(false)}>
            Unloop
            </Text>
        </Flex>
        <Flex>
            <Switcher selected={isOnMute} />
            <Text
            onClick={() => setIsOnMute(true)}>
            Mute
            </Text>
            <Text
            onClick={() => setIsOnMute(false)}>
            UnMute
            </Text>
        </Flex>
    
  

      
            
    </div>
  )
}
const Flex = styled.div`
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: grey;
  height: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`;
const Switcher = styled.div`
  background: black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 41px;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  z-index: 1;
  left: ${({ selected }) =>
    selected === true ? "0px" : "60px"};
`;

const Text = styled.div`
  color: ${({ selected }) => (selected ? "black" : "white")};
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 20;
  line-height: 4px;
  padding: 30;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
export default AudioPlayer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to mute/unmute individual sounds, but play/pause all sounds together, then you will need to create a mute/unmute slider for each sound. I can think of a number of ways to do this. The "best choice" might depend upon the standards in the rest of the application, how many sounds you're importing, and whether they're likely to change.

*Method 1:* One way to do this would be creating one array containing `isOnMute` values for each sound and another array containing all refs, and then `map(...)` over each of the elements of the `isOnMute` array to create your sliders.

*Method 2:* Another way would be to have one array of objects containing all sounds, and then the ref and the `isOnMute` values could be stored within each object. You could `map(...)` over that to create your sliders as well.

*Method 3:* You could also create separate child components for each sound like you said, and then pass the mute property between the parent AudioPlayer and the child AudioChannel components.

Then anytime the play/pause button is clicked, you would need to update each of the refs in the array (via a `forEach` or each of the child components via toggling a single `isPlaying` property).

Regardless of which you choose, I also might like to recommend the [`use-sound` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-sound). It makes managing multiple sounds and their properties a little bit less cumbersome in my opinion, including the ability to play and pause with a single method call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have 8 different sounds to play, and I also need to have a separate row with a different color for each - then I guess the best way is to have a child component for each of them, no? When you said I will have to update each of the refs in the array - what array were you mentioning?

Comment: In method 1, you would have an array of refs that you push to on initial load of the component. That is what you would iterate on. In method 2, you would have an array of audio channels, and you would iterate on that array, playing/pausing each ref within each object. In method 3, there would be no array of refs, since they would be managed in individual child components, and you would update by toggling a passed property like `isPlaying`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet for you/
Also do not forget to use according `id`s instead of `idx` and `idx2`

```
const AudioList = () => {
  /* here populate the array in format: array of objects
  {
    drums: mp3file,
    isPlaying: boolean,
    setIsPlaying: boolean,
    isLooping: boolean,
    setIsLooping: boolean,
    isOnMute: boolean,
    setIsOnMute: boolean,
  }[]
   */

  const [audios, setAudios] = useState([
    { isPlaying: true, isOnMute: false, isLooping: true, drums: "Your mpr" },
  ]); // use initial audios

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // similar to start all, mute all, you have full controll logic over all elements
          // also you could implement add new audiofile, or delete, similar logic :)
          setAudios((audios) =>
            audios.map((audio) => ({ ...audio, isPlaying: false }))
          );
        }}
      >
        Stop all
      </button>
      <div>
        {audios.map((audio, idx) => (
          <AudioPlayer
            key={idx}
            {...audio}
            setIsPlaying={(val) =>
              setAudios((audios) =>
                audios.map((audio, idx2) =>
                  idx === idx2 ? { ...audio, isPlaying: val } : audio
                )
              )
            }
            // similar for setMute and setLopping function,
            // i think you can figure it out, it is just a snippet:)
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const AudioPlayer = ({
  drums,
  isPlaying,
  setIsPlaying,
  isLooping,
  setIsLooping,
  isOnMute,
  setIsOnMute,
}) => {
  const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(drums));

  // also you have full controll of element inside component
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOnMute) {
      audioRef.current.volume = 0;
    } else {
      audioRef.current.volume = 1;
    }
  }, [isOnMute]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audioRef.current.play();
    } else {
      audioRef.current.pause();
      audioRef.current.load();
    }
  }, [isPlaying]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLooping) {
      audioRef.current.loop = true;
    } else {
      audioRef.current.loop = false;
    }
  }, [isLooping]);
  return (
    <div>
      {!isPlaying ? (
        <button
          type="button"
          className="play"
          onClick={() => setIsPlaying(true)}
        >
          <ImPlay2></ImPlay2> Play
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button
          type="button"
          className="pause"
          onClick={() => setIsPlaying(false)}
        >
          <ImStop></ImStop> Stop
        </button>
      )}
      <Flex>
        <Switcher selected={isLooping} />
        <Text onClick={() => setIsLooping(true)}>Loop</Text>
        <Text onClick={() => setIsLooping(false)}>Unloop</Text>
      </Flex>
      <Flex>
        <Switcher selected={isOnMute} />
        <Text onClick={() => setIsOnMute(true)}>Mute</Text>
        <Text onClick={() => setIsOnMute(false)}>UnMute</Text>
      </Flex>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, when you're using audios, is that an array of the audio files? I see that you used  const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(drums)); - drums sound is one sound I want to play combined with other 7 audio files, then how can I use each of them for the ref?

Comment: You push all your `drum`s into array in AudioList as default state for example. And then pass it via props. I edited code a bit to show.

Comment: drums was just an audio file, that's why I wasn't sure if you meant to add audios - so where should I add the rest of the audio files to?

Comment: So you must have array of drums. And `const [audios, setAudios] = useState([
    { isPlaying: true, isOnMute: false, isLooping: true, drums: "Your mpr" },
  ]); // use initial audios` in this line you must put each drums for every item. So that audios array will consist of items where every item is like in example.

Comment: There is no drum for every item, there are 8 different sounds, one is drums, one is vocal, one is guitar, etc... :) So I guess I should ignore the drums array?

Comment: I meant mp3 files. You should put mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following:

I added Audios.js containing:

```
const audios = () => {
    return [
        {
            color: 'lightgreen',
            isOnMute: false,
            audio: drums,
            title: 'Drums'
        }, ...
```

AudioList.js:

```
const AudioList = ({isPlaying, isLooping}) => {
    const [audioToPlay, setAudioToPlay] = useState();
    useEffect(()=> {
        setAudioToPlay(audios())
    },[]) ....//and mapped through <AudioItem>:
```

AudioItem.js:

```
  const AudioItem = ({audio, isPlaying, isLooping}) => {
  const [isOnMute, setIsOnMute] = useState(false);
  const audioRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLooping) {
        audioRef.current.loop = true;
    } else {.... //other functionality
```

added a progressBar.js:

```
const ProgressBar = ({isPlaying}) => {
const [completed, setCompleted] = useState({
    count: 0
});const intervalId = useRef(null)

useEffect(() => {...
```

ControlPanel.js:

```
const ControlPanel = ({
setIsLooping, isLooping, isPlaying, setIsPlaying}) => {
      return ( 
        <div> 
        <PlayButton> //....
```

and Home.js containing controlpanel, AudioList, ProgressBar:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [isLooping, setIsLooping] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div>
        <ControlPanel
         setIsLooping={setIsLooping} //....
```